# ObservableScrollView hamburger icon missing

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout, hamburger-menu

I have an activity with frame layout. When the options are clicked from the navigation drawer, it opens the specific fragment. I was trying to implement observablescrollview in my fragment. https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView. I am able to implement it but I am not getting the hamburger icon in the actionbar. I realized it has to be bundled with the drawertoggle but that resides in my mainactivity. How do i get it in my fragment? Users may not even realize the presence of a navigation drawer without it. It was available when I was using a toolbar in app_bar_main.xml. I hope I have made myself clear. Please let me know if you require any other information. Help a newbie out. Thanks in advance.

Here's the screenshots.

[image]
[image]

Here's my code

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="net.simplifiedcoding.navigationdrawerexample.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">



    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="net.simplifiedcoding.navigationdrawerexample.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_menu_1.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/parallax_image_height"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/example" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/anchor"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/parallax_image_height"
                android:minHeight="@dimen/parallax_image_height" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/body"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/anchor"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:text="@string/lipsum" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableScrollView>

    <include layout="@layout/gradient_header" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
        app:theme="@style/Toolbar" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Menu1.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableScrollView;
import com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableScrollViewCallbacks;
import com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ScrollState;
import com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ScrollUtils;
import com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewHelper;


public class Menu1 extends Fragment implements ObservableScrollViewCallbacks {

    private View mImageView;
    private View mToolbarView;
    private ObservableScrollView mScrollView;
    private int mParallaxImageHeight;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //returning our layout file
        //change R.layout.yourlayoutfilename for each of your fragments
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu_1, container, false);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar((Toolbar)v.findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        mImageView = v.findViewById(R.id.image);
        mToolbarView = v.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mToolbarView.setBackgroundColor(ScrollUtils.getColorWithAlpha(0, getResources().getColor(R.color.primary)));

        mScrollView = (ObservableScrollView) v.findViewById(R.id.scroll);
        mScrollView.setScrollViewCallbacks(this);

        mParallaxImageHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.parallax_image_height);
        return v;

    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
        getActivity().setTitle("Menu 1");
    }


    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged(int scrollY, boolean firstScroll, boolean dragging) {
        int baseColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.primary);
        float alpha = Math.min(1, (float) scrollY / mParallaxImageHeight);
        mToolbarView.setBackgroundColor(ScrollUtils.getColorWithAlpha(alpha, baseColor));
        ViewHelper.setTranslationY(mImageView, scrollY / 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDownMotionEvent() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpOrCancelMotionEvent(ScrollState scrollState) {
    }

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        //add this line to display menu1 when the activity is loaded
        displaySelectedScreen(R.id.nav_menu1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void displaySelectedScreen(int itemId) {

        //creating fragment object
        Fragment fragment = null;

        //initializing the fragment object which is selected
        switch (itemId) {
            case R.id.nav_menu1:
                fragment = new Menu1();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_menu2:
                fragment = new Menu2();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_menu3:
                fragment = new Menu3();
                break;
        }

        //replacing the fragment
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        //calling the method displayselectedscreen and passing the id of selected menu
        displaySelectedScreen(item.getItemId());
        //make this method blank
        return true;
    }


}
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="Toolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

On your `MainActivity#onCreate`, before calling `toggle.syncState()`, call `toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true)`

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true)
toggle.syncState();
```